# Auto download attachments of Outlook with Excel VBA and task scheduler

Tags: excel, vba

I want to download attachments of Outlook automatically using Excel VBA and task scheduler.

```vb
Sub BatchSaveAttachmentsFromTask()
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Dim objShell, objWindowsFolder As Object
    Dim strWindowsFolder As String
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFolder, strFilePath As String

    'Get the task
    Select Case Outlook.Application.ActiveWindow.Class
        Case olInspector
            Set objTask = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Case olExplorer
            Set objTask2 = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End Select

    'Select a Windows folder for saving extracted attachments
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindowsFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder to save Tasks' attachments:", 0, "")

    If Not objWindowsFolder Is Nothing Then
       strWindowsFolder = objWindowsFolder.self.Path & "\"

       If objTask2.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
          For Each objAttachment In objTask2.Attachments
              strFilePath = strWindowsFolder & objAttachment.FileName
              objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFilePath
          Next
       End If

       Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & strWindowsFolder, vbNormalFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

I can run it in Outlook VBA screen to download attachments. I want to use it with task scheduler in Win10.

How can I implement it with Excel VBA and task scheduler?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=task+schedulaer+run+Excel+VBA+macro

Comment: I know it but how can I implement above code block on Excel VBA? Above code block doesn't run on Excel VBA. @TimWilliams

Comment: I missed that part, but since the posted code relies on either the Outlook `CurrentItem` or `Selection`, how would that work when running unattended and there is no-one to select the Task?   Your Excel VBA would need to open up Outlook and then know how to select the relevant item.

Comment: An Outlook event, `ItemAdd` or `NewMailEx` will process incoming items. You need to verify an incoming item is a task and determine or hardcode the Windows folder.